# how to verify that proxychains is working

Tags: tor

I Installed `proxychains` and tor to test them. I heard that proxychains and tor will redirect the message into multiple nodes before getting to the desired destination.

So I thought that it is logical that the TTL of a packet will be less if we use proxy chains, because it will pass through more node. But when I tried the ping command with proxychains and without proxychains, I got the same TTL as a result

So that made me thing that may be proxychains and tor aren't working properly. What can I do to confirm that they are working ?

Comment: You should not scan other people's computers without their permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ping will not help you debug your connection. You are using Tor as a SOCKS proxy. A SOCKS proxy acts at layer 5 of the OSI model (session) to act as a proxy for TCP and UDP connections, of which ping's ICMP requests are not.

If you want to test it, you could point your browser to a website like ipchicken.com or dnsleaktest.com which may help you identify where you appear to be browsing from.

Answer (score 9):

On terminal run the command:

```
 proxychains curl ifconfig.me/ip
```

If you get a result other than your real public ip then you're set.

FYI you can find out your real public ip by the same command `curl ipconfig.me/ip`.

Comment: Site has moved to [ifconfig.me/ip](http://ifconfig.me/ip)

Comment: @DanielStevens answer updated!